# How to break the sound barrier without a heavily restricted character?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, movement

I've seen a number of TikTok and YouTube videos recently about breaking the sound barrier in D&D. The builds proposed by these videos are very restrictive, so I was wondering if this feat could be done with less restricted builds.

For the purpose of this question, "breaking the sound barrier" means physically moving (i.e. not teleporting) at least **6,900 feet** with your movement within one round. This only needs to be achievable reliably (100% of attempts) at least once per day, and you can use any **non-legendary** magic items, multiclassing, and feats. You **may not** use magic items that permanently boost Ability Scores, Epic Boons, or assistance from other characters that you cannot summon yourself.

**What 20th level character build can break the sound barrier with the most liberty remaining in their build?** I consider the following selections to be key to a character build, and thus would rather their liberty be preserved. The less of these that are required for the speed feat, the better the answer.

- Character race
- Character primary class (the class with the most levels)
- Character primary subclass (for the class with the most levels)
- Number of levels needed for multiclass dips
- ASI/feat selections
- Attunement slots

For the purposes of the question, I will treat all of these as equally important to build liberty, so my evaluation of build liberty uses the following formula:

- 1 point if character race is free
- 1 point if the majority of class levels (at least 11) are free
- 1 point if the primary class does not have a required subclass (guaranteed if the primary class if free)
- 1 point for each level that is not restricted (assuming the primary class goes to level 11)
- 1 point for each ASI/feat selection that is free (not counting extra ones from Rogue or Fighter)
- 1 point for each attunement slot that is free

Answer (score 3):

**7 points of build liberty**

### The Character

Our sonic boomer, let's call him Crash, is a 20th level Tabaxi with the following classes:

- Bard 10 ------------------------------------- (for *longstrider*, Jack of All Trades, the Metamagic Adept feat, the Mobile feat, and *Ashardalon's stride* via Magical Secrets)
- Druid (Circle of the Stars) 2 -------------- (for the spell list and Starry Form: Dragon)
- Fighter 2 ------------------------------------ (for Action Surge)
- Monk 2 -------------------------------------- (for Unarmored Movement and Step of the Wind)

...and the following magic items:

- *potion of speed*
- *spell scroll of wind walk*

### The Charge

To break the sound barrier, Crash follows this procedure:

- Use Starry Form choosing the Dragon constellation
- Cast *longstrider*
- Drink the *potion of speed*
- Cast *Ashardalon's stride* with the Extended Spell Metamagic
- Use the *spell scroll of wind walk* (guaranteed due to Starry Form: Dragon, 16 Wisdom, and Jack of All Trades)
- Use Feline Agility
- Take the Dash action
- Take the Dash action using Step of the Wind
- Take the Dash action using the action granted by the *potion of speed*
- Take the Dash action using the action granted by Action Surge

### The Calculation

To start with, here is Crash's base movement speed:

- 300 feet (*wind walk*) **[total so far]**
- 10 feet (Unarmored Movement) **[310 feet]**
- 10 feet (Mobile feat) **[320 feet]**
- 10 feet (*longstrider*) **[330 feet]**
- 20 feet (*Ashardalon's stride*) **[350 feet]**

This is then doubled by:

- *potion of speed* **[700 feet]**
- Feline Agility **[1400 feet]**

Crash can use this speed 5 times due to 4 dashes resulting in **7000 feet**

For the build, he gets:

- 1 point of build liberty since any bard subclass is sufficient
- 3 points of build liberty since 3 levels are flexible after Bard 11
- 3 points of build liberty for free attunement slots

Comment: Where is Cunning Action coming from?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Oops, an earlier form of the build had Rogue levels. I replaced with Step of the Wind from Monk so Mobile isn't necessary

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli This build uses a flying speed, so Boots of Speed don't fit

Comment: Right, right. My bad.

Comment: You can drop 2 of your 10 feet (or the one 20 feet) speed boosts and still meet the brief of 6,900 ft/turn

Comment: @DaleM Because those 10 ft are doubled twice and then X5 from the other traits and the dashes, each 10 feet of speed is 200 feet of movement. I need them all unfortunately

Comment: @DavidCoffron 10x2x5=100 not 200

Comment: @DaleM It is 10x2x2x5. Doubled from *haste* and from Feline Agility

Comment: Longstrider doesn't apply because you are using fly speed not walking speed. Longstrider specifically adds to only walking speed. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111018/does-longstrider-apply-to-other-speeds/111049#111049

Comment: @ITAlex The answer you link to is not the most agreed upon interpretation of *longstrider*. *Longstrider* does not specify walking speed, and therefore, like Unarmored Movement, Mobile, and *Ashardalon's stride* applies to flying speeds as well.

Comment: @DavidCoffron did a bit more research and despite a somewhat convincing argument being made for speed as a whole to always be walking speed, it was countered by a Sage advice saying the opposite.